espeak dictionary - match double letters and replace with singles
I'm using espeak-ng to convert text to phonemes, but it's returning the wrong phonemes in my language when the word contains double n, for example "madonna".
I wanted it to treat such words as "madona".
I tried to create an extra file dictionary, compile it and use but it doesn't matter rule I try to create, it doesn't work.
What I'm doing now is basically creating a list of all the possible words I can think of with double Ns and map them to a single N but it's not the best solution... I just wanted to fix it in a single dictionary rule.
thanks!

Creating a single rule for all double N cases might be difficult. Different contexts can require different pronunciations (e.g. antenna might need two Ns, while madona might not. I recommend writing a script (e.g., in Python) that pre-processes your text before feeding it to espeak-ng. The script can identify and replace double Ns with single Ns based on your rules. You can use various existing text processing, inflectors, natural language processing, ... libraries.

Do you need to fix this directly in espeak, or would a preprocessing step be acceptable?
if you just want to remove double n's, you could pipe your text through tr -s n.

yes, I needed to create a rule in espeak to do that
